# R not producing the same result when the data set source is changed

Tags: r

if i manually create 2 DFs then the code does what it was intended to do:

```
`df1 <- structure(list(CompanyName = c("Google", "Tesco")), .Names = "CompanyName", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df2 <- structure(list(CompanyVariationsNames = c("google plc", "tesco bank","tesco insurance", "google finance", "google play")), .Names =  "CompanyVariationsNames", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))-5L))
 `
```

`test <- df2 %>%
         rowwise() %>%
         mutate(CompanyName = as.character(Filter(length, 
                                           lapply(df1$CompanyName, function(x) x[grepl(x, CompanyVariationsNames, ignore.case=T)])))) %>%
         group_by(CompanyName) %>%
         summarise(Variation = paste(CompanyVariationsNames, collapse=",")) %>%
         cSplit("Variation", ",")`

this produces the following result:

`CompanyName    Variation_1     Variation_2        Variation_3
1:      Google   google plc      google finance      google play
2:       Tesco   tesco bank      tesco insurance          NA`

but..... if i import a data set  (using read.csv)then i get the following error `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Column CompanyName must be length 1 (the group size), not 0`. my data sets are rather large so `df1` would have 1000 rows and `df2` will have 54k rows.
is there a specific reason why the code works when the data set is manually created and it does not when data is imported?

the DF1 contains company names and DF2 contains variation names of those companies

help please!

Comment: We would need to see/be able to upload a subset of your `df1` and `df2`  into our R sessions to explore the difference between your `dput` data and your actual data. There looks to be a problem with the content of `CompanyName` as you can see.

Comment: @mysteRious DF1 contains a list of comapnies like google, IBM, etc and DF2 contains variations names of thos companies like Google Inc, Google Maps, IBM inc, IBM iNvestmets and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing from CSV can be tricky. See if the default separator (comma) applies to your file in particular. If not, you can change it by setting the `sep` argument to a character that works. (E.g.: `read.csv(file_path, sep = ";")` which is a commom problem in my country due to our local conventions.

In fact, if your standard is semicolons, `read.csv2(file_path)` will suffice.

And also (to avoid further trouble) it is very commom for csv to mess with columns with decimal values, because here we use commas as decimal separators rather then dots. So, it would be worth checking if this is a problem in your file too, in any of the other columns.

If that is your case, you can set the adequate parameter in either `read.csv` or `read.csv2` by setting `dec = ","` (E.g.: `read.csv(file_path, sep = ";", dec = ",")`)